# Flutter: title color is changing once I apply it on another custom widget

Tags: flutter

I've a custom widget "UserProfileBanner"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserProfileBanner extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserProfileBanner({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 16),
      tileColor: Colors.green,
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1WQyxvFCUeq3tRuWTQRb32tl3IsTb84mX'),
        radius: 24,
      ),
      title: Text('User Name'),
      subtitle: Text('User Email'),
    );
  }
}
```

Another widget "ScreenBackground"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

import '../utility/asset_utility.dart';

class ScreenBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const ScreenBackground({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          AssetUtility.backgroundSVG,
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
      ),
      child
    ]);
  }
}
```

Once I put my "UserProfileBanner" on "ScreenBackground" tileColor: Colors.green, become disappear. **What can I do to return my titleColor?**

Here is my main screen code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:task_manager2/ui/widgets/screen_background.dart';
import 'package:task_manager2/ui/widgets/user_profile_banner.dart';

class AddNewTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddNewTaskScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ScreenBackground(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              UserProfileBanner(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 24, right: 24),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Add new task',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 32, color: Colors.green),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Title',
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextFormField(

                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description', alignLabelWithHint: true),
                      maxLines: 6,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                            width: 120,
                            height: 40,
                            child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){},style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.green), child: const Text('Add'),)),
                        const SizedBox(width: 25),
                        SizedBox(
                            width: 120,
                            height: 40,
                            child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.green), child: const Text('Cancel'),)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just need to return my profile banner title color here and need the solution in an alternative ways.